# Convert HTML to text with AjaxToolkit HtmlEditorExtender inside a gridview

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a text field in database with HTML code, and I need to display, in a tabular, form all text entered.

I'm using ASP.NET with VB.

I've built a Gridview and I'm trying to use the AjaxToolkit HtmlEditorExtender to convert the HTML into readable text, but I'm still seeing the HTML tags when I Debug the page. See code below.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SQL_Comments">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Group" HeaderText="Group" 
                SortExpression="Report_Group" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Period" HeaderText="Period" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Period" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="comment" SortExpression="comment">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("comment") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("comment") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                    <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="_Comment_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                    </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Any help/ideas on how to get this sorted will be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by editing the templateField as follows:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="comment" SortExpression="comment">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("comment")) %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CommentForPeriod" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("comment"))  %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="_Comment_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="CommentForPeriod">
                    </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```